# Understanding a quote from Steven Strogatz

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

While studying calculus and differential equations I thought refreshing and refining the basics may be a good idea. I try to get a deeper insight and more intuition for derivatives and integrals. So I have read the book *Infinite Powers - The story of Calculus, the language of the universe* from Steven Strogatz.

## Problem

At the beginning of chapter 4 and in other parts of the book he wrote this:

> "Differential calculus cuts complicated problems into infinitely many
> simpler pieces. Integral calculus puts the pieces back together again
> to solve the original problem." - Steven Strogatz

## My Background

I consider myself to have a solid foundation of calculus, nontheless I can't wrap my head around which picture he is drawing with this sentence.

## Ideas

I always thought of derivatives and integrals as of division and multiplication of non-constant values / functions. Comparing the images below show this idea for integrals.

[Multiplication / Constant function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Y7l.png)

[Integral / Non-constant function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHkIT.png)

In one part Steven says something like, that derivatives zoom infinitely close till the viewed section of the graph is / looks linear. So a graph is split into sections which represent a part of the entire "problem", but this don't seem to be the whole story.

## Question

Problems are split into easier chunks with differential calculus (derivatives), solved for each part seperately and be put back together with integral calculus (integrals). This is not clear how this process could look like. Can somebody elaborate this further please? Maybe with a concrete example which is close to reality.

Comment: I think it is a figurative way to explain how calculus works as an analogy for others problem which can be solved reducing them to an ensemble of small problems.

Comment: With differential calculus, I often used logarithmic differentiation to solve more complicated problems. Basically using properties of logs to bust a complicated function into sums of simple functions for easy differentiation.

With integral calculus, you're often taking chunks of a differentiated function and kinda throwing it back together. That's a good description of techniques like integration by parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concrete example: arc length of a curve.

Look at the curve that is formed by graphing $y = f(x)$.

To find the arc length, you first divide up the curve into many small pieces; infinitesimally each piece is the graph of a linear function. If we were to look at a piece that is near $(x,f(x))$, the piece has slope $f'(x)$.

For this small piece, the arc length can be found by geometry: you are looking at the graph of a linear function, so the horizontal distance is $\Delta x$, and the vertical distance is $f'(x) \Delta x$, so Pythagoras tells you that the length of the hypotenuse (the linear piece that you are interested in) is $ \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} \Delta x$.

Reassembling the infinitesimal contributions you find the general arc length formula
$$ \int \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} ~dx $$
via integration.

Comment: Thanks, that made it very clear. 
For everyone following, I calculated an example:
A half circle: $f(x)=\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}$ from $((x-2)^2+y^2)=4$ has the derivative $$f'(x)=-\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{-(x-4)x}}$$.
These two points represent $P_1=(x_1,f(x_1))=(1,\sqrt{3})$ and $P_2=(2,2)$ pieces.
The derivative $f'(x)$ give the arc length formula $$g(x)=\int_0^4{\sqrt{1+(-\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{-(x-4)x}})^2}dx} \approx 6.28$$ with its maximum boundaries as integral boundaries. This give the suspected result regarding $\frac {1}{2}*2*\pi*r=\pi * 2 \approx 6.28$.

Comment: BTW, in the format of the cosmic brain meme, what Strogatz referred to is probably only level 2 or level 3 of calculus understanding. There are at least one or two more levels beyond that. Pity I don't have nice quotes capturing them readily available.

Comment: Do you have some references to find them or some book titles?

Comment: Higher level understanding is based firmly on the concept of convergence and approximations, so you will need to learn some real analysis first to really appreciate it. I don't know if there are any pop sci accounts readily available.